# Karma/Testacular opens browser without extensions

Tags: google-chrome, karma-runner

When I run Karma (formerly Testacular) with 'browsers' configured to 'Chrome' and 'Firefox', 2 browser instances indeed open, however the extensions/plugins appear to be missing while I want them running with my tests.

I've configured:

`CHROME_BIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` and `FIREFOX_BIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`

It kinda looks like the launched Chrome instance is of a different installation or something, as it doesn't have all my Chrome bookmarks (neither the extensions, as written).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the index.js like this:

```
this._getOptions = function(url) {
    // Chrome CLI options
    // http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
return [
    '--user-data-dir=' + this._tempDir,
    '--no-default-browser-check',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--disable-default-apps',
    '--disable-popup-blocking',
    '--start-maximized',
    '--load-extension=' + '<your path to the extension>/2.0_0'
].concat(flags, [url]);
```

where

```
<your path to the extionsion>
```

is something like this:

```
/Users/dannyb/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji
```

That weird number is the extionsion ID that you can find in your extensions page in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how chrome is run on karma, along with some other command line flags, it disables default apps
on start up. I myself am looking for how to turn these features off, but no luck yet.
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/blob/master/index.js

Comment: yeah, saw it already, but still couldn't make it work although I played with those different parameters. Thanks.